# Twisted Deferred not displaying unhandled Exception without errback

Tags: python, exception, twisted, deferred

I'm reading through McKellar and Fettig's [Twisted Network Programming Essentials, 2nd Ed.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025016.do)

I am running Twisted 15.5.0 on Python 2.7.10 on Windows 7.

In the section about `Deferred` there's an example that is supposed to raise an `Unhandled Error in Deferred` - but I am only getting complete silence from the console when I run the minimal example below:

#### Minimal example

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

def raiseErr(err):
    raise Exception(err)

d = Deferred()
d.addCallback(raiseErr)
d.callback("oh no")
```

`$ python test.py
(no output)`

#### Minimal example from actual book text

The actual example from the book is along these lines:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

def callback1(result):
    print "Callback 1 said:", result
    return result

def callback2(result):
    print "Callback 2 said:", result

def callback3(result):
    raise Exception("Callback 3")

def errback1(failure):
    print "Errback 1 had an an error on", failure
    return failure

d = Deferred()
d.addCallback(callback1)
d.addCallback(callback2)
d.addCallback(callback3)
d.callback("Test")
```

And the expected output is listed in the book as:

> `callback3` raises an `Exception`, and because there is no registered `errback` to handle the `Exception`, the program terminates and reports an `Unhandled Error` to the user. The result is:

```
Callback 1 said: Test
Callback 2 said: Test
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/test.py", line 33, in <module>
d.callback("Test")
<...>
File "/tmp/test.py", line 11, in callback3
raise Exception("Callback 3")
exceptions.Exception: Callback 3
```

Am I doing something wrong?

## EDIT:

I have gotten the error to display correctly on my machine.

To enable the error to get logged without having an `errback` handler on the `Deferred` object, I needed to add the following to my snippet:

```
import sys
from twisted.python import log

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

# rest of the code goes here
```

Now, when I run my minimal example from the first code snippet in my question, I get the following output:

```
2016-02-05 09:45:43-0600 [-] Log opened.
2016-02-05 09:45:43-0600 [-] Invalid format string or unformattable object in log message: '%(log_legacy)s', {'format': '%(log_legacy)s', 'log_legacy': <twisted.logger._stdlib.StringifiableFromEvent object at 0x038913F0>, 'time': 1454687143.778, 'message': (), 'log_time': 1454687143.778, 'log_namespace': 'twisted.internet.defer', 'log_level': <LogLevel=critical>, 'log_source': None, 'system': '-', 'isError': True, 'log_logger': <Logger 'twisted.internet.defer'>, 'log_format': 'Unhandled error in Deferred:'}
2016-02-05 09:45:43-0600 [-] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "testd.py", line 13, in <module>
            d.callback("oh no")
          File "C:\Swat\.virtualenvs\twisted\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 393, in callback
            self._startRunCallbacks(result)
          File "C:\Swat\.virtualenvs\twisted\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 501, in _startRunCallbacks
            self._runCallbacks()
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "C:\Swat\.virtualenvs\twisted\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
            current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
          File "testd.py", line 9, in raiseErr
            raise Exception(err)
        exceptions.Exception: oh no
```

So, now I can verify that Twisted does indeed raise an error as it is meant to - it just didn't feel like telling me for some reason. If anyone can elaborate as to why that would be the default case for handling an exception without an errback defined, I'd love to know.

I've changed the title to reflect my new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question after hitting a very similar issue whilst working my way through Dave Perticola's excellent [Twisted Introduction](http://krondo.com/an-introduction-to-asynchronous-programming-and-twisted/) specifically in [Part 9: A Second Interlude, Deferred](http://krondo.com/a-second-interlude-deferred/) he has an [example](http://github.com/jdavisp3/twisted-intro/blob/master/twisted-deferred/defer-unhandled.py) similar to the one you have posted:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
def callback(res):
    raise Exception('oops')
d = Deferred()
d.addCallback(callback)
d.callback('Here is your result.')
print "Finished"
```

Just like you I did not get the output that was suggested:

```
Finished
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
--- <exception caught here> ---
 ...
exceptions.Exception: oops
```

I initially assumed a versioning issue, Twisted 16 with PyPy 5.0.1 on EL6 for me, but research led me to here; and then when turning on logging, as suggested in another answer, had no effect on to what I think is the actual answer.

The clue to my answer was in the tutorial I was working from with a statement of:

> *the reason that “Finished” comes first is because the “Unhandled” message isn’t actually printed until the deferred is **garbage collected**.*

For some reason, for you and I, by the time the garbage collector gets around to doing its thing it no longer has anywhere to output to. If you want to see this is true, here is my modified code:

```
import gc
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
def callback(res):
    raise Exception('oops call')
d = Deferred()
d.addCallback(callback)
d.callback('Here is your result.')
d = None
gc.collect()
print "Finished"
```

I guess the real answer is to deal with your Exceptions before the garbage collector gets to them, but perhaps this bit of info will let you sleep a bit easier even if we don't know why it works for some, we know what is causing our expected error messages to disappear.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for satisfying my curiosity, this had been kinda driving me crazy in the back of my mind. I've given you the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is nothing wrong with our code.

I tried here running:

```
$ python deferred.py
```

And the output was:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deferred.py", line 8, in <module>
    d.callback("oh no")
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/asyncproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 393, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/asyncproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 501, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/asyncproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "deferred.py", line 4, in raiseErr
    raise Exception(err)
exceptions.Exception: oh no
```

I am using Twisted 15.5.0 and Python 2.7.6.

P.S: It was not necessary to initialize the log. It worked without it.

Comment: I believe that it works for you - but it doesn't work for me. Why would that be? I've tried this in both Git BASH and Windows command prompt, so it doesn't seem to be a setting in my terminal that is ignoring the error message.

Comment: I've also tried setting up another VirtulalEnv from scratch, with the same result.

Comment: An interesting detail - if wrap `d.callback` in a `try/except` clause, the `except` does not fire at all! Yet this all works as expected on my Debian machine.

Comment: Have you tried switching from Python 2.7.10 to 2.7.9 or lower? I've found 2.7.10 to have acted weird at times.

Comment: @pie-o-pah 2.6.6 failed to install twisted, I'll see if I can get 2.7.9 somehow.

Comment: @jcfausto Did you run this on Windows?

Comment: @pie-o-pah 2.7.9 has the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This code gives the same result on all of my Windows machines I've tested on, and none of the Linux machines. I am concluding that this is an issue with something to do with Windows, twisted, or pywin32.